# Creating and starting a task on the UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, task

When a method that gets called on a worker thread needs to run code on the UI thread and wait for it to complete before doing something else, it can be done like this:

```
    public int RunOnUi(Func<int> f)
    {
        int res = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(f);

        return res;
    }
```

But what if I wanted to do it with tasks? Is there a way for the RunOnUi method to create a task that is started on the UI and return it so that the caller (which runs on a worker thread) can wait for it? Something that will fit the following signature: `public Task<int> StartOnUi(Func<int> f)` ?

One way to do it is as follows:

```
public Task<int> RunOnUi(Func<int> f)
{
    var task = new Task<int>(f);
    task.Start(_scheduler);

    return task;
}
```

Here, assume that `_schduler` holds the ui `TaskScheduler`. But I am not too comfortable with creating "cold" tasks and using the start method to run them. Is that the "recommended" way or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: This should be an operation that you do quite rarely.  If you find yourself doing something like this a lot, it's a sign that your program isn't well designed.  In a UI envirionment you should typically have most of your code running in the UI thread, and only have very localized sections that have no UI interaction being offloaded elsewhere and being `await`-ed.  Whenever you feel the need to do this it's usually a sign that you should be extracting the UI code out of the operation.

Comment: You are right. This is a special case where a WPF application performs as a WCF service. Each service call is received on a worker thread that needs to await a task that does something on the UI (either perform changes or read some values in it).

Comment: e.g. WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async must be run in UI thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [`InvokeAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199385(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Invoke` then return the `Task<int>` inside the [`DispatcherOperation<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199421(v=vs.110).aspx) the function returns.

```
//Coding conventions say async functions should end with the word Async.
public Task<int> RunOnUiAsync(Func<int> f)
{
    var dispatcherOperation = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(f);
    return dispatcherOperation.Task;
}
```

If you do not have access to .NET 4.5 it is a little more complicated. You will need to use [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap the [`DispaterOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation(v=vs.100).aspx) that `BeginInvoke` returns

```
    public Task<int> RunOnUi(Func<int> f)
    {
        var operation = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(f);
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        operation.Completed += (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult((int)operation.Result);
        operation.Aborted += (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetException(new SomeExecptionHere());

        //The operation may have already finished and this check accounts for 
        //the race condition where neither of the events will ever be called
        //because the events where raised before you subscribed.
        var status = operation.Status;
        if (status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult((int)operation.Result);
        }
        else if (status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Aborted)
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(new SomeExecptionHere());
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is only supported in .NET 4.5 and above.

Comment: @KevinD. Fair enough, I will update with a pre 4.5 solution too.

Comment: @KevinD. Just noticed that the OP must be on 4.5 because `Dispatcher.Invoke<T>(Func<T>)` is a 4.5 only feature too.

Comment: A solution for .net 4.5 is what I am looking for, thanks guys