# How to wait for an element to be visible with time out in WebView2 in .NET 6.0. Specifically how to access UI thread

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, webview2, ui-thread

In .NET 6.0 using WebView2, I'm trying to wait for a period of time to see if an element becomes visible in the DOM (essentially what Selenium WebDriverWait does, but in WebView2).

I think this code should do that:

```
internal async Task<bool> WaitForElementToBeVisible(FormWebView2 formWebView2, string element, int numberOfSecondBeforeTimingOut) 
{
    using CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    try 
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => {
                while (true) {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Stop the task if cancelled in the outer catch
                    string webPage = await formWebView2.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.innerHTML"); // Get the web page using JavaScript
                    string decodedWebPage = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(webPage);

                    if (decodedWebPage.Contains(element))
                        break; // Stop checking

                    await Task.Delay(100); // Wait 1/10th of a second before checking again
                }
            }).WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numberOfSecondBeforeTimingOut));

        // If the task ran to completion, ie the element exists,
        Debug.WriteLine("Element exists");

        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException) 
    { 
        // If the task created in try timed out,
        Debug.WriteLine("Timed out after " + numberOfSecondBeforeTimingOut + " seconds");
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); // Cancel the task
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: CoreWebView2 can only be accessed from the UI thread.

I'm way over my head trying to figure out how to run this on the UI thread.  [Creating and starting a task on the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194943/creating-and-starting-a-task-on-the-ui-thread) looks helpful, but the answer no longer seems to be available in .NET 6.0.

Suggestions, hopefully with sample code, would be very welcome.

Comment: I don't know about WebView2.  I will say this much:  Did you test without Task.Run()?  Just running the code inside the try..catch.

Comment: Instead of waiting in a software loop inside the procedure, it would be better to check whether it has completed using a timer event. You should choose the timer to use depending on which UI is being implemented. [System.Windows.Forms - Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer), [System.Windows.Threading - DispatcherTimer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer)

Comment: The task structure works with a wait Task.Delay().  The exception appears to be caused by the ExecuteScriptAsync().

Comment: The question is when has it completed?  I can wait for the NavigationCompleted event, but elements may become visible after that occurs.  That's why I think I need to wait for a specific element to be present.  Does DispatcherTimer exist in .NET 6.0?  I believe System.Windows.Threading has been replaced by System.Threading, and it's not giving me DispatcherTimer.

Comment: `ExecuteScriptAsync()` must run on the UI Thread! (period).

Comment: So, wouldn't it be better to check for completion with a process equivalent to `if (decodedWebPage.Contains(element))` in the timer event handler? As shown on the reference page, isn't DispatcherTimer also compatible with .net 8.0 in the Windows environment?

Answer (score -1):

This works using a Stopwatch to check for a time out:

```
     internal async Task<bool> WaitForElementToExist(FormWebView2 formWebView2, string element, int secondToWait) {
        string webPage = await formWebView2.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.innerHTML"); // Get the web page using JavaScript
        string decodedWebPage = Regex.Unescape(webPage);
        int numberOfMillisecondsToWait = secondToWait * 1000; // Convert to milliseconds
        bool elementExists = false;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();// Create new stopwatch
        stopwatch.Start();// Begin timing
        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < numberOfMillisecondsToWait) { // While it has not timed out,
            if (decodedWebPage.Contains(element)) { // If the element is in the DOM,
                elementExists = true;
                break; // Stop checking
            }
            await Task.Delay(100); // Wait 1/10th of a second before checking again

            // Check the web page that currently exists
            webPage = await formWebView2.webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.innerHTML"); // Get the web page using JavaScript
            decodedWebPage = Regex.Unescape(webPage);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop(); // Stop the stopwatch
        return elementExists;
    }
```